# Eclipse code formatter profile using SonarQube squid rules

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, formatter, sonarlint-eclipse

I am looking for some pointers on generating eclipse code formatter xml file using squid rules defined in SonarQube. Please suggest how to do this using SonarLint or any other opensource plugin available.

CheckStyle plugin lets me currently generate eclipse code formatter rules using CheckStyle --> Create Formatter-Profile menu entry by right clicking on the project. I can configure the project to use generated code formatter profile so that when I right click on the file and click on "Apply Checkstyle fixes", those fixes are applied from the generated profile.

Comment: Why? What do you plan to do with such a file?

Comment: Since SonarQube doesnt support checkstyle,findbugs, pmd anymore, I would like to have the same functionality for at least the rules related to formatting. So that I could configure eclipse to use the generated rules for fixes.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to create a rule file and import it onto Eclipse. Instead, simply install [SonarLint for Eclipse](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html), and use [connected mode](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html#Connected) to apply the rules activated on your SonarQube server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I am not looking to create and import a rule file. By using the connected mode in SonarLint plugin, I could analyze the project using the quality profile defined in SonarQube server. Once I see the issues in eclipse,I was wondering if there is a solution to generate eclipse code formatter profile for formatting(checkstyle) related rules.

Comment: What would you do with it? You're going to apply CheckStyle rules via eclipse, and then ... export the formatter profile for import into SonarQube?

Comment: With CheckStyle plugin, there is a feature to generate Eclipse code formatter profile. A project could be configured to use the generated formatter profile so that when you do a "CTRL+SHIFT+F" shortcut or "Apply CheckStyle Fixes", all the formatting issues are fixed.

Comment: With the new SonarLint plugin, is there a way to generate fixes for formatting related issues automatically?

Comment: There isn't yet

Comment: Thank you. Is this feature in development or do you have any plans for supporting that feature in the near future?